# How to configure the lxd bridge in trusty?

Tags: 14.04, networking, lxc

According to [this article](https://stgraber.org/2016/10/27/network-management-with-lxd-2-3/), you can set up basic lxd networking with:

```
lxc network create testbr0
lxc network attach-profile testbr0 default eth0
```

However, the lxc network command doesn't exist in the version of lxc/lxd available in trusty. How can I do the same thing in trusty?